# How to add Content Types List on a Page and use it to create NEW document/list based on type selected?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, javascript, content-type, modal-dialog

I need to show all content types in a drop-down or as hyperlinks along with description on custom .aspx page. When user selects any type, respective **New Form** should open to create a new document/list out of that content type.

Please help me to achieve this in SharePoint 2010 using Designer.

Answer (score 0):

This will be very hard for Site ContentTypes, since there could be multiple Lists, which support it. - So no New Form.
You could however try to achieve this for a single list, like this:

```
<div>               
        <input id="TestBtn" name="Button1" type="button" value="Script test" onclick="getContentTypesOfSite()" /><br />
        <br/ >
        <table id="testTable" style="width:100%; border: 1px solid black;">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Link</th>
                <th>GUID</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
        </table>
        <br />
    </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
        var debug_mode = 1;

        var thisSiteUrl = L_Menu_BaseUrl;

        function getContentTypesOfSite(siteUrl) {
            if (SP) {
                var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
                var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("Aktionsliste");
                this.collList = oList.get_contentTypes();


                clientContext.load(collList, 'Include(Name, Id, Description, Hidden, Group, NewFormUrl)');

                clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onSiteQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onSiteQueryFailed));
            }
        }

        function onSiteQuerySucceeded() {

            var listInfo = '';

            var listEnumerator = collList.getEnumerator();
            $('#testTable').find('tbody').empty();

            while (listEnumerator.moveNext()) {
                var oContentType = listEnumerator.get_current();

                if ((!oContentType.get_hidden() === true) && (oContentType.get_group() != '_Hidden')) {
                    var link = '/Lists/Aktionsliste/NewForm.aspx';
                    var row;
                    if (oContentType.get_newFormUrl() == "") 
                        row = $('<tr><td>'+oContentType.get_name()+'</td><td>'+oContentType.get_description()+'</td><td><a href="'+link+'">New Form</a></td><td>'+oContentType.get_id()+'</td></tr>');
                    else
                        row = $('<tr><td>'+oContentType.get_name()+'</td><td>'+oContentType.get_description()+'</td><td><a href="'+oContentType.get_newFormUrl()+'">New Form</a></td><td>'+oContentType.get_id()+'</td></tr>');
                    $('#testTable').find('tbody').append(row);
                }
            }

        }

        function onSiteQueryFailed(sender, args) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(args));
            alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
        }


    </script>
```

Please don't forget to insert/enable jQuery.